# Python 3.5 bdist_rpm custom Installation path

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpm-spec

I need to install my python code under /opt/MSDB/ but I cannot work out how to embed this as part of the RPM package using the command below. How would I change the default install location?

```
python3.5 setup.py bdist_rpm
```

I've had a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/dist/creating-rpms.html) but the --spec-file option hasn't been implemented as far as I can tell?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up using the rpm-maven-plugin, as I knew and understood how to use this.